# How to improve/edit in this UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

How can I improve this UML class diagram and what mistakes I made?

I'm really confused about the relationship between Expense and Category, because Category and Expense can exist by themselves: you can register Expense and not assign it to a category, or do the opposite, you can add new Categories to the categories list, and so on...

Do I really need separate List classes?

[image]

Comment: If you explain the semantics of CategoryList it would be possible to give a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just make your CategoryList the Category class and delete the latter. I don't know your domain, but assuming an expense can be assigned one or more categories you can clarify this by adding a multiplicity. You should also drop the shared composition (hollow diamond) as it does not add any real information to your model.

**Edit** According to your comment I would model it like this:

[image]

The representation of Category as a list would be task of some View or Controller that represents existing categories. One could think of your CategoryList class as such a controller.

Comment: The main idea was that user can pick a Category from a Category list to assign it to Expense or he can skip this step, so Expenses could exist without categories and one Expense could be assigned just to one Category.
"You should also drop the shared composition (hollow diamond)" - should I just use association?

Comment: You mean there are several lists, or is it just one list with all Categories?

Comment: There is one list with all categories, you can pick a category ar add new one and pick it.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I would not leave the multiplicity on the `Expense` side undefined.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I was concentrating on the other side. Also (from a personal convention set in many projects) a left out multiplicity was defined as 0..n. But being explicit is better, I guess.